# Array miscalculation?

Tags: arrays, scanf

This is probably really basic but im just a bit confused, im not sure if this is working properly, because the sum is only printing 0. im not sure if its a problem with the loop or what? could someone please help, thanks

I am trying to read in 6 different voltages, then print the sum of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int sum, average, reading, i ;
 float volt[6];
int main(){
sum = 0;
printf("Enter 6 voltages: ");
for(i=0; i<=5; i++){
  scanf("%f",&volt[i]);

}
printf("%4.1f",volt[i]);
}
```

Comment: You never add anything to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Add the voltages to the sum:

```
int main(){
    float sum = 0.0;
    float volt[6];
    printf("Enter 6 voltages: ");
    for (int i=0; i<=5; i++) {
        scanf("%f",&volt[i]);
        sum += volt[i];
    }
    printf("Here is the sum: %4.1f", sum);
}
```